# Generate WAV and add a second (stereo) channel

Tags: php, audio, wav, channel, riff

I found the following incedibly code on stackoverflow. Please can anybody help me adding a second channel (stereo)

There will be nchannels = 2
The file size must (somehow) be increased and the 2. array (i.e. samples2) must be added.

When I try I only achieve a higher frequency.

Thanks  alot from germany : Martin

```
$freqOfTone = 440;
$sampleRate = 44100;
$samplesCount = 80000;

$amplitude = 0.25 * 32768;
$w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;

$samples = array();
for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++) {
$samples[] = (int)($amplitude *  sin($n * $w));
}

$srate = 44100; //sample rate
$bps = 16; //bits per sample
$Bps = $bps/8; //bytes per sample /// I EDITED

$str = call_user_func_array("pack",
array_merge(array("VVVVVvvVVvvVVv*"),
    array(//header
        0x46464952, //RIFF
        160038,      //File size
        0x45564157, //WAVE
        0x20746d66, //"fmt " (chunk)
        16, //chunk size
        1, //compression
        1, //nchannels
        $srate, //sample rate
        $Bps*$srate, //bytes/second
        $Bps, //block align
        $bps, //bits/sample
        0x61746164, //"data"
        160000 //chunk size
    ),
    $samples //data
)
);
$myfile = fopen("sine.wav", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $str);
```

Comment: Don't worry :D takes time and I remember starting out myself. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> SELF SOLUTION: I checked the recorder.js Web Worker, found the SPEC and how to use it. Here is a slightly modified code for a tone going from the right speaker to the left in 1 sec. Maybe it helps somebody.
>
> ```
> $freqOfTone = 440;
> $sampleRate = 44100;
> $samplesCount = 80000;
>
> $amplitude = 0.25 * 32768;
> $w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;
>
> $samples = array();
> $samples2 = array();
> for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++) {
>     $samples[] = (int)($amplitude*($n/$samplesCount) *  sin($n * $w));
>     $samples2[] = (int)($amplitude*(1-$n/$samplesCount) *  sin($n * $w ));
> }
>
> function interleave($l,$r){
>  $data=array();
> $ix=0;
> for($i=0;$i<count($l);$i++){
>    $data[$ix++]=$l[$i];
>    $data[$ix++]=$r[$i];
>  }
>  return $data;
> }
>
> $stereo=interleave($samples,$samples2);
>
>
> echo(count($samples));
> echo(count($stereo));
>
> $srate = 44100; //sample rate
> $bps = 16; //bits per sample
> $Bps = $bps/8; //bytes per sample /// I EDITED
>
>
> $samples_merge=array_merge($samples,$samples2);
>
> $str = call_user_func_array("pack",
>     array_merge(array("VVVVVvvVVvvVVv*"),
>        array(//header
>           0x46464952, //RIFF
>            80000*2*2+36,      //File size  *2*Channels +36
>         0x45564157, //WAVE
>         0x20746d66, //"fmt " (chunk)
>         16, //chunk size
>         1, //compression
>         2, //nchannels
>         $srate, //sample rate
>         $Bps*$srate, //bytes/second
>         $Bps, //block align
>         $bps, //bits/sample
>         0x61746164, //"data"
>         80000 * 2 *2 //chunk size (filesize * 2 *Channels)
>     ),
>     $stereo // Stereo tone left[0], right[0], left[1], right[1], ...
> )
> );
> $myfile = fopen("sine.wav", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
> fwrite($myfile, $str);
> fclose($myfile);
> ```